# How to create bootable usb drive , with bootsector written in nasm?

Tags: assembly, usb, nasm, boot

i have the following simple code :

```
    mov ah ,  0x0e    
    mov al , `h`    
    int 0x10    
    mov al , `1`    
    int 0x10    
    jmp $
    
    
    
    times 510-($-$$) db 0 
    dw 0xaa55
```

I then compile it and run it normally in qemu:

```
    nasm -fbin boot_sect.asm -o boot_sect.iso 
    qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,file=boot_sect.iso
```

After padding zeros until 14 MB i create a bootable usb. My issue is that this usb does not boot on my laptop. Is the problem related to my laptop or is it because of the usb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wasn't actually the code as i thought inititialy . I only had to change to the csm mode from bios settings and then boot from usb .